# Error running manage.py syncdb for first time on Heroku: "You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file"

Tags: django, heroku

When executing `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` on a django app I recently deployed to heroku, i get the following error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("You need to specify NAME in your Django settings file.")
```

I understand what the error means.  I'm just not sure why its occurring.  I am pretty much following the current [heroku deployment guidelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) to a tee.

I have dj_database_url==0.2.1 and pycopg2==2.4.4 in my requirements.txt. I set up my app with `heroku-postgresql:crane`.  In my settings.py, I have:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

The weird thing is, I already have 3 successful deployments on Heroku of this same repo, so its not like I'm starting from scratch here.

Comment: The thing i just noticed is that my other deployments have DATABASE_URL defined in the config, whereas my new deployment does not. Is something I have to add manually?  I don't remember doing so for the others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out.  I needed to run

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>
```

This part is conspicuously absent from the tutorial, and I remember having to hunt for this last time I did this.

Comment: Awesome! This was a huge help.

Comment: Thanks so much! Completely missing from the tutorial.

Comment: Its weird because this only happened to me when i used Crane database.  I'm pretty sure that this step is unnecessary when using a Dev database, because it seems to get Promoted automatically to the DATABASE_URL.